# How to check last line of .cpp file executed before runtime error occurs?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VSC++ 2013. Is it possible to check which was the last line that was being executed in the main program file before a run time error stopped the program?

For example

```
int main()
{
   foo (a,b,c);
}
```

where foo() is a function stored in an external library. Now when the debugger stops the program due to any error, it points to a line in the foo() function. Is there some option in the VS that will tell the debugger to report the error location in the main function and not where the actual error occured?

Comment: It seems you're looking for a stack trace (in Visual Studio, the Call Stack pane).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the stack trace, there is an option for that. It will show you the call trace, and you can go up to the `main` itself.

You might want to have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for general debugging options in Visual Studio, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Call Stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace your stack to see where the error takes place. You can also put break points in your function and see what happens. You can Step forward (by F10) and step in to functions (by F11).